# Do atoms and molecules affect light rays

Tags: visible-light, diffraction

Molecules of air are all around us all the time. If so, during daylight do rays from the sun diffract as it passes through molecules in the air? and if so is this diffraction negligible to be noticed? plus does this affect anything?

Molecules move at high speeds and at random directions so their diffraction effect must be low, however as their are an infinite number of various air molecules in the atmosphere certainly there must be *some sort of effect*

Also how and why is the skies blue **fixed**? *(molecules don't stay at the same place they move randomly)*  and why isn't the air below the stratosphere seem blue? are there any required criteria's for the diffraction by molecules to be noticeable?

Comment: Ever wondered [why the sky is blue](http://spaceplace.nasa.gov/blue-sky/)?

Comment: "as their are an infinite number of various air molecules in the atmosphere..." most definitely not! Infinity is something very different from just some big number (though physicists often "approximate" big numbers by $\infty$, but only for the purpose of taking some convergent limit).

Comment: There is absorption (greenhouse effect), dispersion (rainbow) and scattering (blue sky) just to name a few effects

Comment: @MarkMitchison question updated

Comment: @leftaroundabout so how do they state that at the center of a blackhole is a region where the spacetime curvature becomes infinite? It should rather be a big number that's not infinite if your saying is to be correct. Could you prove that your proof is correct? *(maybe a link)*

Comment: @KDawG: general relativity predicts the curvature becomes infinite at the singularity, but most of us believe quantum gravity will become significant as you get very close to the singularity and the curvature will remain finite. Physicists are generally reluctant to believe infinities occur in the real world.

Comment: *"Also how and why is the skies blue fixed? (molecules don't stay at the same place they move randomly)"* For the same reason that all the furniture and objects in the place where you are seem fixed. Their molecules are really moving extremely fast, but there are so many of them and they are so small and fast that your eye cannot notice the difference from one moment to the next as they move to slightly different positions.

Comment: @KDawG: as John Rennie says, quantum gravity probably prevents that anyway. _Anyway_, the spacetime curvature being infinite is quite another issue (a bit like, you're standing still and would therefore take infinite time to reach your destination: it is a somewhat hypothetical statement that is neverless correct for given assumptions/definitions); compared to talking about an _infinite number of molecules_, which is just absurd for something like the atmosphere, where you could theoretically even count them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Molecules of air are all around us all the time. If so, during daylight do rays from the sun diffract as it passes through molecules in the air? and if so is this diffraction negligible to be noticed? plus does this affect anything?

While both diffraction and scattering refer to redirection, I think *scattering* is the better term here.  The molecules in the air are sufficient to scatter some of the light as it travels through the atmosphere.  Aerosols also perform some absorption and additional scattering.  I'm not sure what you might mean by "does this affect anything?".

> why isn't the air below the stratosphere seem blue?

There's not enough of it between you and an obvious background.  Water is blue as well.  But in a tall glass, you can't see that.  In a white bathtub, you can probably tell when the water is high.  In a lake or ocean, you can tell easily.

Answer (score 0):

Re: diffraction of light by molecules in the air.

The distances between atoms in molecules is approximately $0.1 nm$ which is about $5000$ times smaller than the wavelength of visible light.

For diffraction effects to occur the structure should have similar dimensions to the wavelength of light - in this case the molecules are just too small for diffraction to occur.

Mark Mitchison#s link above covers the sky is blue...